# How to set pop up background Transparent Java Fx

Tags: java, javafx, gif

I am trying to show a success message gif from my javaFx application.

```
public static void successGif() {
    int size = 400;
    ImageView splash = new ImageView(new Image("file:src/main/resources/img/success3.gif"));
    splash.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
    splash.setFitWidth(size);
    splash.setFitHeight(size);
    splash.setPickOnBounds(true);
    Pane splashLayout = new Pane();
    splashLayout.getChildren().add(splash);
    final Stage initStage = new Stage();
    Scene successScene = new Scene(splashLayout, size, size);
    successScene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    initStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    initStage.setWidth(size);
    initStage.setHeight(size);
    initStage.setScene(successScene);
    initStage.show();
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Platform.runLater(initStage::close);

    }).start();
}
```

The above function can create a popup with a gif successfully. for now, I tried calling this function through a button in my application and the background of the popup is still white. But when I tested the same function by calling it in the start() function of the application, it works as expected. how can I fix this issue?

I need to call this function inside my application on many occasions.

How to make the background transparent.

The following is the gif in case you need to try, Thanks.

[image]

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `javafx.scene.Group` instead of adding splash layout directly to the scene,
You can change your void method `successGif()` to,

```
public static Stage successGif() {
    int size = 600;
    ImageView splash = new ImageView(new
    Image("file:src/main/resources/img/success3.gif"));
    splash.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
    splash.setFitWidth(size);
    splash.setFitHeight(size);
    splash.setPickOnBounds(true);
    Pane splashLayout = new Pane();
    splashLayout.getChildren().add(splash);
    final Stage initStage = new Stage();
    Group group = new Group();
    group.getChildren().add(splashLayout);
    //        group.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
    Scene successScene = new Scene(group, size, size);
    successScene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    initStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    initStage.setWidth(size);
    initStage.setHeight(size);
    initStage.setScene(successScene);
    initStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    initStage.show();
    return initStage;
}
```

and then if you want the Stage object, then you can just get the returned object from the method